# What's the differences between the catalysts?

Tags: dark-souls

I can't seem to figure out what the differences are between the different catalysts or rather how they affects me.

e.g.) When a catalysts scales with int, does that mean that magic does more damage or that melee does more damage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it exactly right. Catalysts affect magic damage the same way that swords affect melee damage.

A catalyst with 150 magic damage will do more damage than a catalyst with 100 magic damage (before scaling), and a catalyst with A magic scaling will do more damage than a catalyst with C magic scaling (assuming they have the same base magic damage).